# join/merge 2 status tables (check statuses at any change)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables indicating since when is the status valid for an object. I need to kind of join/merge/union them so I know in one table what are the both stuses at any given change.

Table1:

```
Object  status1 date
Obj1    Open    1998-01-01 00:00:00.000
Obj1    Closed  2000-06-01 00:00:00.000
Obj1    Open    2008-03-06 00:00:00.000
Obj1    Closed  2013-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

Table2:

```
Object  status2 date
Obj1    ACTIVE  1999-01-01 00:00:00.000
Obj1    INACTIV 2000-08-29 00:00:00.000
Obj1    UNKNOWN 2004-05-06 00:00:00.000
Obj1    check   2014-05-01 00:00:00.000
```

as result I would need such thing:

```
Object  status1 status2 date
Obj1    Open    NULL    1998-01-01 00:00:00.000
Obj1    Open    ACTIVE  1999-01-01 00:00:00.000
Obj1    Closed  ACTIVE  2000-06-01 00:00:00.000
Obj1    Closed  INACTIV 2000-08-29 00:00:00.000
Obj1    Closed  UNKNOWN 2004-05-06 00:00:00.000
Obj1    Open    UNKNOWN 2008-03-06 00:00:00.000
Obj1    Closed  UNKNOWN 2013-01-01 00:00:00.000
Obj1    Closed  check   2014-05-01 00:00:00.000
```

here the script to create the source tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table2](
[Object] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
[status2] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
[date] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[table2] ([Object], [status2], [date]) VALUES (N'Obj1', N'ACTIVE', CAST(0x00008D3F00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[table2] ([Object], [status2], [date]) VALUES (N'Obj1', N'INACTIV', CAST(0x00008F9D00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[table2] ([Object], [status2], [date]) VALUES (N'Obj1', N'UNKNOWN', CAST(0x000094DF00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[table2] ([Object], [status2], [date]) VALUES (N'Obj1', N'check', CAST(0x0000A31E00000000 AS DateTime))
go
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table1](
[Object] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
[status1] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
[date] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[table1] ([Object], [status1], [date]) VALUES (N'Obj1', N'Open', CAST(0x00008BD200000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[table1] ([Object], [status1], [date]) VALUES (N'Obj1', N'Closed', CAST(0x00008F4400000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[table1] ([Object], [status1], [date]) VALUES (N'Obj1', N'Open', CAST(0x00009A5700000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[table1] ([Object], [status1], [date]) VALUES (N'Obj1', N'Closed', CAST(0x0000A13900000000 AS DateTime))
```

anyone has an idea?
Tomek

Comment: Great script for creating your tables and data for your specific example. +1

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea. First you union both tables leaving nulls for other table's status, then use `case` and correlated sub-queries to fill the nulls with last previously existing value.

```
WITH CTE_Union AS 
(
    SELECT  [Object], status1, NULL AS status2, [date] FROM dbo.Table1
    UNION 
    SELECT [Object], NULL AS Status1, status2, [date] FROM dbo.Table2
)
, CTE_RN AS 
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Object] ORDER BY [date]) RN  
    FROM CTE_Union
)
SELECT 
    r1.[Object]
    ,CASE WHEN r1.status1 IS NULL THEN (SELECT status1 
                                        FROM CTE_RN r2 
                                        WHERE r2.RN = (SELECT MAX(RN) 
                                                       FROM CTE_RN r3 
                                                       WHERE r3.status1 IS NOT NULL AND r3.RN < r1.RN)) 
                                  ELSE r1.status1 
            END AS status1
        ,CASE WHEN r1.status2 IS NULL THEN (SELECT status2 
                                        FROM CTE_RN r2 
                                        WHERE r2.RN = (SELECT MAX(RN) 
                                                       FROM CTE_RN r3 
                                                       WHERE r3.status2 IS NOT NULL AND r3.RN < r1.RN)) 
                                  ELSE r1.status2 
            END AS status2
    ,[date]
FROM CTE_RN r1
ORDER BY RN
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a0efa/2)**

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
select 
  isnull(t1.object,t2.object) Object 
  ,status1
  ,status2
  ,isnull(t1.date,t2.date) date
from table1 t1
  full join table2 t2
    on t1.Object = t2.Object
      and t1.date = t2.date
order by 4
```

Comment: If this is not it, but close, explain to me how you determined what should be in the place of NULL in those columns.  Are just carring it down from the previous record?  If so, are you OK with a stored procedure that uses a cursor?